# Rendering a page in PHP: How?

Tags: php, javascript, html

This may be a inappropriate question for SO, but I thought lets see :)

I'm writing a website in php. Every pageload may have 10-20 DB requests.
Using the result of the DB queries I need to generate a page.

The page would contain a topic (should be image or text) followed by comments. There could be mutiple topics like this.

Currently, I'm creating a string using the DB result and sending it to the browser.
When browser receives the string (as an ajax response), it parses using split functions and creates the HTML dynamically.

I'm basically a C++ programmer; relatively new to web development. So, I do not have fair understanding of the JS objects. How long of a string can JS variable hold? Is it ok to use split and generate HTML at the client.

I'm not generating the complete HTML at the server side to avoid any overhead because of string concatenation. I believe sending less no. of characters to the client (like I'm doing) is better as compared to sending complete HTML code.

Is something (or everything) wrong in my understanding :)
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Well, I'll be highly grateful if I could get opinions in yes/no. What would you recommend. Sending HTML to the client or a string that will be used at the client to generate HTML?

Comment: Note that when a user doesn't support JS, the page will be left blanc...

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) (and in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)) is a pretty common string-based way of sending data to a browser.

Comment: @SiteSafeNL: Thats all right; I believe this case should be 2% or something!!

Comment: Note, this really isn't an opinion site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, I think you should look into generating the HTML with PHP and sending it directly to the browser. PHP was built specifically for this purpose.

Comment: I'm under the impression that sending the HTML (in turn generating it) at the server side will cost more time as compared to generating it at the client. How might this difference affect the user experience with the website :)

Comment: sure it'll create some more data to transfer between the server and client, but as Kibbee says, php is made for generating html, javascript isn't. You really want to move as much parsing to the server as possible.

Comment: PHP can generate the same HTML with much less computing time than would take in Javascript, because in Javascript, you are manipulating a big XML document, whereas when dealing with PHP you're basically just pushing string (which happens to contain HTML) to the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you be best off to look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and more specific to the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method of that library. Also, take a look at [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and you should be all good to go.

Comment: Maybe you want to also add information about how to encode the data on server-side to JSON (for PHP, see `json_encode`; http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a templating engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)?
It's pretty simple to use, take a look at the crash course, you might like it! http://www.smarty.net/crash_course